# Rendering different html in reusable components

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to make a reuseable component, which takes in an array and a variable, then i want to map through that array and return html.
But when i reuse this component, the html wont necesarly be the same each time i use it. For example:

```
Home Component
 <div className='home'>
    <Mappedarray array={list} pattern={pattern}/>
  </div>

 Account Component
 <div className='account'>
  <Mappedarray array={users} pattern={pattern}/>
  </div>

 function Mappedarray(props) {
   const {array, pattern} = props
    const arrayrow = array?.map(el=>{
    return VARIABLE_HTML
    })
  }
```

So this is the basic set up, now for the VARIABLE_HTML, I want to return different html elements, for example, in the `Home Component` I want to return

```
<Link to={el.link}>
   <p>{el.title}</p>
    <i className={el.src}'></i>
</Link>
```

But for the `User Component`, I want to return

```
<div className='usercont'>
   <img src={el.src}/>
    <p>{el.title}</p>
 </div>
```

I've been using a solution like passing a boolean variable to the component to determine what html should be used, but the component will get very messy and doesn't seem like a good solution.
For example, in the `Home Component` I would pass down:

```
<Mappedarray array={list} pattern={pattern} home={true} />
```

Then in the `Mappedarray Component` I would do

```
 function Mappedarray(props) {
const {array, pattern, home, user} = props
const arrayrow = array?.map(el=>{
return <>
 {
  home?
  <Link to={el.link}>
    <p>{el.title}</p>
    <i className={el.src}'></i>
  </Link>
   :user?
   <div className='usercont'>
    <img src={el.src}/>
    <p>{el.title}</p>
   </div>
    :ANOTHER_VAR?
    ...
  }
 </>
})
}
```

Therefore, by doing it like this it would get very messy and disorganized, looking to a more dynamic way of doing this

Comment: What will your list contain exactly, components, strings that indicate the elements you want?

Comment: They will contain strings, images or icon classNames (font awesome) but no string that contains the element i want because sometimes i would like to put an extra element

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are mapping trough same array and want different result maybe reusable component is not for this the best case. But if you want to have this united into one component like this you can just add a flag `isLink` to your reusable component and you are done:

```js
function Mappedarray(props) {
  const { array, pattern, isLink } = props;
  const arrayrow = array?.map((el) => {
    return isLink ? (
      <Link to={el.link}>
        <p>{el.title}</p>
        <i className={el.src}></i>
      </Link>
    ) : (
      <div className="usercont">
        <img src={el.src} />
        <p>{el.title}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Than this would be usage of that component in two cases:

```js
Home Component
<div className='home'>
  <Mappedarray array={list} pattern={pattern} isLink={true}/>
</div>

Account Component
<div className='account'>
  <Mappedarray array={users} pattern={pattern}  isLink={false}/>
</div>
```

**NOTE**
If you just put `isLink` with no `={true}` it will be implicitly true. But for this example i added it explicitly

Comment: Yes sorry, I had recently updated my post, I was using this before but found it to be excessive and would be too messy, would most likely have different use cases in other components.

Comment: well the way i did it its the same as you did with update. So there is not much else to do

Answer (score 0):

You can accept a `render` function as a prop. But if you are doing that then your `Mappedarray` isn't doing much of anything.

```
function Mappedarray({ array = [], render }) {
    return (
        <div>{array.map(render)}</div>
    );
}
```

You can define render components for various types.  Make sure that you are setting a `key` property since we will use this as a callback for `.map`.

```
const MyLink = ({ link, title, src }) => (
    <Link to={link} key={link}>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <i className={src}></i>
    </Link>
)
```

You would call `Mappedarray` by passing the function component as the `render` prop.  Your `array` prop would be an array of props for that component.

```
const Test = () => {
    return (
        <Mappedarray 
            array={[{ link: "/", title: "home", src: "/images/home.jpg" }]} 
            render={MyLink}
        />
    )
}
```

[With Typescript Types](https://tsplay.dev/mL9JaW)

---

You could also tweak this slightly to pass the array `index` as a prop to the `render` component instead of passing it as a second argument.  This version allows for both class components and function components to be passed to `render`.

```
function Mappedarray<T>({ array = [], render: Render }: Props<T>) {
    return (
        <div>{array.map((props, index) => (
            <Render {...props} index={index} />
        ))}</div>
    );
}
```

[With Typescript Types](https://tsplay.dev/w18a8W)